# How to fix "Error in x[(i - z):(i + y)]: only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts?

Tags: r, database, function

I have this dataset which includes all the sales for a company in a given year (company code = `gvkey`, year = `fyeqarq`, sales = `realsales`). After calculating the yearly growth rates for sales (`growth_rates_adjusted`), I try to calculate the volatility of these growth rates. The function used to work with a previous dataset, but is now displaying the above-mentioned error message:

> Error in x[(i - 4):(i + 5)] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts ".

The only difference from the current dataset to the previous one, is that it has more observations.

I've seen other threads where it suggested to add brackets in `x[i - 4:i + 5]`, but that didn't solve the issue.

Here is the code segment where the issue is happening. I'll be happy to provide further info if required.

```
volatility <- function(x){
  out <- rep(NA, length(x))
  for(i in (1+4):(length(x)-5)){
    out[i] <- sqrt((x[i] - mean(x[(i-4):(i+5)]))**2 /10)
  }
  return(out)
}

rs$volatility <- do.call("c", by(rs$growth_rate_adjusted, rs$gvkey, volatility))
```

Sample from data:

```
structure(list(gvkey = c(1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 
1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 
1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 
1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 
1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1009L, 
1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 
1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 
1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 
1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 
1010L, 1010L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 
1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1013L, 1013L, 
1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L), fyearq = c(1978L, 1979L, 1980L, 
1981L, 1982L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 
1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 
1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 
2017L, 2018L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 
1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1978L, 1979L, 1980L, 
1981L, 1982L, 1983L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 
1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 
2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 1982L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 
1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 
1995L, 1982L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L), realsales = c(80.0787687494763, 
83.9880322921772, 72.041255647813, 90.2599788213429, 82.3597655295938, 
79.275697273582, 99.6691746379825, 98.6531307837496, 119.231183761451, 
130.671738596922, 152.401835452683, 177.004920650438, 182.331045530932, 
163.067223699202, 145.669513553658, 142.637840975044, 138.071087623594, 
1686.92046529749, 1944.33679952995, 2503.3850493653, 3430.96847893947, 
3399.78918423465, 2846.26399241784, 2106.69883444041, 1878.94931648818, 
1904.88753225045, 2111.0686482661, 2440.41820615184, 2821.72739990673, 
3568.88502043553, 3764.78124834279, 3431.75866279315, 4563.51718325686, 
5125.57023176176, 5364.4, 4324.89803940838, 3825.52083333333, 
3945.16600024812, 3652.23958087506, 3927.3539111424, 1291.78670435397, 
6.98252898777813, 8.38595031948278, 9.05059463817779, 9.0048500089815, 
7.90239455877713, 7.75665012953149, 13.1293381562225, 12.8158816415637, 
12.7200911507786, 13.9056813962124, 246.549622751016, 308.437038299807, 
214.374965214003, 500.237423535655, 649.926491449795, 635.909445745511, 
500.535949689884, 483.239029553041, 205.834769664682, 105.739312088838, 
82.683671636429, 91.7347403849525, 98.6318765979783, 139.826310815655, 
131.670619277222, 133.607292062286, 101.488303007798, 126.121590249565, 
138.43476531424, 1371.26398397061, 1626.47062842463, 1721.53939149708, 
1698.52423521911, 1545.76404347257, 1387.97100335562, 1199.52374984334, 
976.286828209051, 5855.71181123345, 2177.63623496108, 1.60587804282341, 
1.76472892510185, 1.87719762561912, 2.55263784794121, 2.08909646128974, 
1.23409178557655, 1.14123164970623, 1.16824714048294, 1.33027594980446, 
1.72123053551082, 1.59079093947271, 21.7875798026698, 56.9127173542448, 
30.4252240218178, 31.3298868354637, 31.1716546537136, 32.2110476766607, 
51.9341774935405, 61.2178911442429, 61.86586263717), growth_rate_adjusted = c(NA, 
0.0488177278915325, -0.142243797340123, 0.25289291545105, -0.0875273116049197, 
-0.037446297183831, 0.257247530652708, -0.0101941634203694, 0.208589963787459, 
0.0959527069559234, 0.166295306767067, 0.161435622639821, 0.0300902645018133, 
-0.105652999332261, -0.106690417306896, -0.0208119908185, -0.0320164222918163, 
11.217767632108, 0.152595418413553, 0.287526446020315, 0.370531664639181, 
-0.00908760744851222, -0.162811622080449, -0.259837161959523, 
-0.108107297649273, 0.0138046383341219, 0.108237947135951, 0.156010823312755, 
0.156247479548253, 0.264787314519994, 0.0548900361837266, -0.0884573534508115, 
0.329789659376153, 0.123162250942545, 0.046595745924674, -0.193777861567299, 
-0.11546565988949, 0.0312755235502229, -0.0742494534715727, 0.0753275693379953, 
-0.671079629292128, NA, 0.200990405361887, 0.0792568872189554, 
-0.00505432306108666, -0.122429074232749, -0.0184430716742389, 
0.692655713093963, -0.0238745099660853, -0.00747435825830534, 
0.0932061123918326, 16.7301360304552, 0.251014034652528, -0.304963611388244, 
NA, 0.299236044468932, -0.0215671247266992, -0.212881719183966, 
-0.0345567988624188, -0.57405185203053, -0.486290327620088, -0.218042277720125, 
0.109466217082404, 0.0751856514127895, 0.417658424827343, -0.0583273025717256, 
0.0147084656827421, -0.240398473456934, 0.242720456562112, 0.0976293990609434, 
8.90548855887399, 0.186110513684643, 0.0584509559601001, -0.0133689396778527, 
-0.0899370103640783, -0.102080935821528, -0.135771751035635, 
-0.186104628327237, 4.99794204124976, -0.628117587552114, NA, 
0.0989183973143732, 0.0637314314496069, 0.359813060225522, -0.181593086941546, 
-0.40927007993941, -0.0752457288474235, 0.0236722235872695, 0.138693948999988, 
0.293889839746277, -0.0757827573628338, 12.6960673222665, 1.61216334580085, 
-0.465405529093955, NA, -0.00505051877720075, 0.0333441722774686, 
0.61230947887394, 0.178759231372385, 0.0105846751793586)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
>
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is due to `length(x)` being less than 10.

Comment: Help for debugging: run `x[{
print(sprintf("i is %d, so i-4 is %d and i+5 is %d", i, i-4, i+5));
(i - 4):(i+5)
}]`

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @AndrewGustar the length(x) is actually quite big

Comment: @MichaelChirico sorry for my lack of knowledge. Should I input this directly into the function or outside of it?

Comment: @Christoph updated the post with a sample, is this what you were looking for?

Comment: that's a drop-in replacement for your original `x[(i-4):(I+5)]`

Comment: @CreditDefaultSwap In this context `length(x)` is the number of elements with the same value of `gvkey`.  What is `max(table(rs$gvkey))`?

Comment: Please have a look at the dput function.

Comment: @AndrewGustar the result was 41

Comment: @Christoph used it, but the output is fairly big, should I post it here? Or is there some way to send it directly to you?

Comment: @MichaelChirico thank you, I replaced it but couldn't really find the origin of the error. What is printed is exactly want I "want" it to be. But I still get the error message. How should I interpret this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use a subset eg [1:10,]...

Comment: @CreditDefaultSwap Sorry - not thinking - that should be `min(table(rs$gvkey))`

Comment: @AndrewGustar no problem, result is 1

Comment: @Christoph updated the sample with the first 100 rows from the dataset, as you suggested, using dput

Comment: @CreditDefaultSwap So that is where the problem lies - `length(x)`, for the subset of `rs$growth_rate_adjusted` for that shortest `rs$gvkey` is 1. So you have negative index values: the loop `(1+4):(length(x)-5)` will count from 5 down to -4.  You will need to build something into your function to cope with these short vectors.

Comment: @AndrewGustar true, I thought it was weird in the beginning because when cleaning the data I specified that each company should have at least 11 years of sales (in other words, 11 gvkeys), but just realized I ran that in the wrong part of the code. The sales were first divided in quarters, I should have run the filter after combining the quarters into years. Well, its working now. Thank you!